# Exportar una consulta a Excel

Tags: laravel, excel, exportar

hola a todos estoy intentando exportar una consulta sql a excel con el paquete Maatwebsite, pero no logro que me funcione y me arroja el siguiente error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1096 No tables used (SQL: select * order by `Bit_id` desc limit 1000 offset 0)

este es mi codigo

```
    <?php
namespace App\Exports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class BitacoraExport implements FromQuery
{
    use Exportable;
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
    */
    public function query()
    {
        return DB::query(' 
        tb_bitacora.Bit_id,        
        tb_ssee.Sse_nombre, 
        tb_tipo_incidencia.Tic_Nombre, 
        tb_areas.Are_Nombre, 
        tb_viainforma.Vin_Nombre,
        users.name,
        tb_bitacora.Bit_Descripcion, 
        tb_tipo_equipo.Tpq_nombre,
        tb_marca.Mar_nombre,
        tb_modelo_equipo.Mod_nombre,
        tb_areas.Are_Nombre,
        tb_estado.Est_Nombre,
        tb_bitacora.Bit_Seguimiento,
        tb_bitacora.Bit_Solucion,
        tb_bitacora.Bit_Fecharep, 
        tb_bitacora.Bit_Horarep, 
        tb_bitacora.Bit_Fechasol, 
        tb_bitacora.Bit_Horasol, 
        tb_bitacora.Bit_Adjuntos
        FROM tb_bitacora
        INNER JOIN tb_ssee ON tb_bitacora.Bit_Sse_id = tb_ssee.Sse_id
        INNER JOIN tb_tipo_incidencia ON tb_bitacora.Bit_Tic_id = tb_tipo_incidencia.Tic_Id
        INNER JOIN tb_areas ON tb_bitacora.Bit_Sol_id = tb_areas.Are_Id
        INNER JOIN tb_viainforma ON tb_bitacora.Bit_Vin_id = tb_viainforma.Vin_Id
        INNER JOIN users ON tb_bitacora.Bit_Usu_id = users.id
        INNER JOIN tb_tipo_equipo on tb_bitacora.Bit_Tpe_Id = tb_tipo_equipo.Tpq_id
        INNER JOIN tb_marca on tb_bitacora.Bit_Mar_id = tb_marca.Mar_id
        INNER JOIN tb_modelo_equipo on tb_bitacora.Bit_Mod_id = tb_modelo_equipo.Mod_id
        INNER JOIN tb_estado ON tb_bitacora.Bit_Est_id = tb_estado.Est_Id"')
        ->orderby ('Bit_id','DESC');
    }
}
```

y este es es el codigo desde donde llamo la funcion de exportar.

```
 public function exportExcel()
    {
        return Excel::download(new BitacoraExport, 'bitacora.xlsx');
    }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Pareciera que te falta indicarle la tabla `DB::table('tb_bitacora') ...`. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results

Comment: esta mas abajo el from, pero si cambio la consulta y la hago asi :eturn DB::query('tb_bitacora',' 
        tb_bitacora.Bit_id,        
        tb_ssee.Sse_nombre, .....
me muestra el mismo error

Comment: Usa un modelo eloquent en vez de query builder.

Comment: es qeu no se como hacer los JOIN en eloquent :(

Comment: Bueno, tampoco estás haciendo los joins con query builder https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins . Con eloquent puedes usar todos los métodos de query builder mas los propios de eloquent.

Comment: ok, le daré un vistazo a la documentación para así mejorar mi código, gracias

Comment: Eso, dale una leída para ver cómo se usa query builder. Hice una búsqueda rápida y encontré [esto](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/181#issuecomment-49772951) que dice el desarrollador de laravel excel, por eso te dije que uses eloquent en vez de query builder. [Aquí la documentación](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/exports/from-query.html) de la librería.